# Running a bash file through php doesn't work but running it in PuTTY does

Tags: php, bash

I have this php code:

```
$output = shell_exec("sh /backups/turnon.sh");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

It is in a file that is 0777 file permissions.

This is the contents of the .sh file. It also has 0777:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u root screen -S ftb -X stuff 'java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -jar mcpc.jar
'
```

The screen `ftb` already exists and running the bash file through putty using `/backups/turnon.sh`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sudo` in most systems, is configured _not_ to allow you to execute without a real user logged into a tty (which PuTTY is). Look into `requiretty` [in the sudoers manual](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html) and understand that it is an important security measure.

Comment: PuTTY was open at the time anyway, so I don't think that's the issue (unless I misunderstood you). Is there a way to send it to the root screen?

Comment: I mean that when you are logged in with PuTTY (which is an SSH connection) you have a TTY, and can execute commands via `sudo`.  PHP does not have a TTY login if you are calling it via the browser, or cron or something, and `requiretty` will prevent the execution if it is configured in `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: If you need to get a non-interactive user into the root screen, I have no idea how to do that. You might consider taking it over to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski From my research requiretty isn't on debian (or it's not disabled in the same way that people say to disable it)

Comment: Whatever your problem is, 0777 permissions are **wrong** and **dangerous**. If you do not understand the permissions model at all, guessing is a very poor way to reach a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `sudo` requires you to type in a password to launch the `screen` command, unless you've configured it to do otherwise.

There is no interactive terminal (tty), for you to type your password, when running PHP's shell_exec() function.